# Adding logic to README.md for github page

Tags: html, github, markdown, gif

I was thinking it'd be really cool to have a slideshow on the README.md page of my github repository to show progress of the program (GUI-based) since early development.

One way to do this would be to generate a GIF of the "slide-show" with various images. Is there a better way to do this?

Update: Found that you can create a github webpage with pages.github. Maybe I can add logic to this website rather than a ReadMe file.

Comment: README.md contains markdown. Markdown can contain arbitrary HTML, including JavaScript scripts. And it's quite easy to implement a slideshow using JavaScript.

Comment: Really? Could you give me a quick sample code or good resource to do this? I've turned to using the github pages + jssor

Comment: to do what? A slide show in JavaScript? You simply need to make the next div visible and the previous one invisible at the click of the next button, don't you? There are an awful lot of JS tutorials online, and probably many libraries allowing to do a slideshow in a an even simpler way.

Comment: Alright. I'll look into it. I'm at a 3rd grade reading level of javascript and html, so I was hoping you could ease the pain of figuring it out. I guess I'll go challenge myself and learn something now..

Answer (score 0):

Case closed:

As JB Nizet said above, I can do this easily in markdown.

My current solution, however, is to use github pages.